# How can Cocos2dx particle system achieve a burst effect?

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-engine, cocos2d-x-3.0, particle-system

I am new to Cocos2dx, and I am playing with the awesome particle system in my game. However, I couldnt able to design the best effect in my mind.

What I would like to see is [something like in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YlBinFC9So).

I think the main difference is that I cannot configure to let all the particles appear at once and disappear at the same time afterward. The particle generation time seems to be random.

So my questions will be: **Is there any workarounds that I can configure the effect like that link in Cocos2dx?** Or **is there any other suggested ways for me to stick with?**

I have another solution in my mind which is use sprite animation instead. But then it will lose the flexibility. I love a configuration approach similar as particle system that can easily create different visual effect by only changing parameters.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can download Particle Editor for Cocos2dx and V-play from below link:-

http://games.v-play.net/particleeditor/

also you can show a demo here for various particle effects:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wUrf_veEvU